# Import SQL lite database in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, import

I have created a database in sql lite. I want an exact replica of that database in Msql. Can anybody please tell me how to do that. I have exported the database in .rdb file, but i am not able to import that in Mysql

Comment: the sqlite file is useless - you need to export the database as sql queries, e.g. use whatever sqlite's equivalent of "mysqldump" is, which will take the db and dump it into a series of `create` and `insert` queries in plain text.

Comment: thanks Marc, i used the dump created by sql lite, but had to edit that file because of some syntax issues.